# Does there exist an upper bound on the $\frac{\lVert F \rVert_F}{\lVert F \rVert}$ ratio knowing that F is the sum of two matrices?

Tags: matrices, ratio, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

Let
$$
J =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 0 & \dots & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\ \ \ \ \ K=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & k_{11} & \dots & k_{1n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & k_{n1} & \dots & k_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
two $N \times N$ matrices and F = J+K.

Doing some numerical experiments I noticed that the following relation holds:
$$
\frac{\lVert F \rVert_F}{\lVert F \rVert} \leq \frac{\lVert K \rVert_F}{\lVert K \rVert} + \frac{\lVert J \rVert_F}{\lVert J \rVert}
$$
where $\lVert . \rVert_F$ is the Frobenius norm and $\lVert . \rVert$ is the spectral norm.

Is it true for all K? How can I prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's true and the result is rather trivial. In general, suppose
$$
J=\pmatrix{0&u^T\\ v&0},\,K=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&B}\text{ and }F=J+K=\pmatrix{0&u^T\\ v&B}.
$$
Then
$$
\|J\|_2=\max\{\|u\|_2,\|v\|_2\}=\max\{\|Fe_1\|_2,\|e_1^TF\|_2\}\le\|F\|_2
$$
and $\|K\|_2=\|B\|_2\le\|F\|_2$ because $B$ is a submatrix of $F$. Therefore
$$
\frac{\|K\|_F}{\|K\|_2} + \frac{\|J\|_F}{\|J\|_2}
\ge\frac{\|K\|_F+\|J\|_F}{\|F\|_2}
\ge\frac{\sqrt{\|K\|_F^2+\|J\|_F^2}}{\|F\|_2}
=\frac{\|F\|_F}{\|F\|_2}.
$$